# Lazy-loaded @ManyToOne column get overriden to null after calling @Repository.save()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Boot project, I have the following `@ManyToOne` relationship field referring to the same `@Entity` as parent.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="workspace")
public class Workspace extends AbstractEntity {
    @NaturalId
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(name="default_workspace", referencedColumnName="code")
    private Workspace parent;

    private String name;
    private String shortName;
}
```

The lazy-loading behavior is working as expected. However, every time I call `@Repository.save()` on this `@Entity`, the `default_workspace` field will get set to `NULL`.

**UPDATE: Include some configurations requested in the comment**

To enable lazy-loading using Hibernate, I simply included the `hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin` plugin in my `pom.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.ft</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ft.admin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ft</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.ft.common</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <configuration>
              <failOnError>true</failOnError>
              <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

To perform the CRUD procedures on my `Workspace`, I use the following `@Repository`.

```
@Repository
public interface WorkspaceRepo extends CrudRepository<Workspace, Integer> {
    Optional<Workspace> findByCode(String workspaceCode);
}
```

By default, in Spring Boot, the boundary of a transaction stays within each call to the `@Repository`. Hence, to be able to access my lazy-loaded field without running into `LazyInitializationException: no Session`, I added `@Transactional` to my `@Service` to expand the transaction boundary as following.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AppAdminService {
    @Autowired
    private WorkspaceRepo workspaceRepo;

    public void updatePsyWorkspace() {
        Workspace childWorkspace = workspaceRepo.findByCode("PSY").get();
        childWorkspace.setShortName("PSY SHORT");
        workspaceRepo.save(childWorkspace);
    }
}
```

When I execute `WorkspaceRepo.findByCode(code)`, I get back a child record with a valid non-null `parent`. However, whenever I execute `WorkspaceRepo.save(childWorkspace)`, the `parent` gets set to `NULL` and the `default_workspace` column becomes `NULL` in the database as well even though I only updated the `ShortName` field as shown in the above example.

**UPDATE: Temporary solution**

As a temporary solution, I had to include a plain `String` field for the `default_workspace` column and exclude the `parent` field from Hibernate operations as following.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="workspace")
@Getter @Setter
public class Workspace extends AbstractEntity {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn(
        name="default_workspace", 
        referencedColumnName="code",
        insertable=false,
        updatable=false)
    private Workspace parent;

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Column(name="default_workspace")
    private String defaultWorkspace;

    public void setParent(Workspace parent) {
        this.parent           = parent;
        this.defaultWorkspace = (parent != null) ? parent.getCode() : null;
    }

    ...
}
```

By using `AccessLevel.NONE`, I completely hide this field from the outside world. Any calls to update the `parent` field will additionally update the `defaultWorkspace` field. Even though this solution works, it doesn't feel right to me.

I'd be very grateful if you could show me a better way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Would you please show us the codes to configure the  Workspace and its properties ? And you save(workspace) or save(workSpaceParent) ?

Comment: @KenChan: Thanks for trying to help :). I've updated my post with more details as requested. Please let me know if I can add anything else for you.

Comment: The codes looks good to me except that you don't need to call `save()` explicitly.  Behind scene, it  calls `entityManager` 's `merge()` which is intended for updating the value in detached entities back to the DB. You don't need to call it since you just get the entities from DB and it is still in the managed state.  Just change its status and hibernate will figure it need to be updated.

Comment: My suggestion is try to remove that save() . But based on the codes , it should work even you include it. So , I suspect the problem may be caused by that Hibernate bytecode enhancer which is something that I am not so familiar with it .

Comment: @KenChan. Thanks for taking a look. As I'm using Spring Data JPA, I'm not accessing Hibernate `session` or the `entityManager` directly. I'm not so sure how I can update an entity status to dirty. I tried to remove the `save()` call as you suggested but after the method `updatePsyWorkspace()` completes, there was no SQL generated to update the database at all.

Comment: @KenChan. By the way, I did find a temporary solution :). I updated my post to include it. It works but it feels hacky to me. If you have any suggestions, I'd love to hear them. Thank you!

Comment: I know you use spring-data .To update an entity to dirty , just change some mapped properties of the entities you retrieved , hibernate will issue an update SQL when the transaction commit theoretically , but apparently not your case now.....

Comment: @KenChan. I think I knew what happened :). I'm actually using Spring `@Cacheable` to cache the result of `findByCode`. As a consequence, in the 2nd call, I got the cached object from the cache which is detached and I must call `save()` explicitly to update the entity in the database. Now come to think of it... It doesn't seem like a right thing to do anymore...

Comment: Glad to hear you find the reason.Maybe for the update case , you need to switch to the non-cache version, normally we cache the things that are seldom need to be updated......